# Authenticity of reference

Tags: hadith, source-identification

I need the authenticity of a narration mentioned in a few tafsirs:

> “Hafiz Ahmed bin Musa bin Mardawayh has narrated with his isnad from
> Abdullah Ibn Masud that: “During the lifetime of the Holy Prophet (s)
> we used to recite this verse as: “O Apostle! Deliver what has been
> sent down to you from your Lord; ‘**that Ali is the Maula of the**
> **Momineen’, if you don’t….”**
>
> Tafseer Ruh al Ma’ani, Volume 9 page 193 (cf. [Tafseer Mazhari Vol 3, p.353](http://www.shiapen.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/tafseer_mazhari_v3_p353.jpg) )

It is alleged that Ali was originally mentioned in the Qur'an (Q 5:67) and I need someone to verify if the narration's chain is authentic (or perhaps if it's shaadh).

Answer (score 2):

This narration is mentioned by Imam Al-Suyuti in his Tafseer, along with many other different narrations that belong to this specific verse (which he **didn't condition** on authentic Hadiths or narrations). His intention was to simply collect and reference all the narrations he found and then compile them; whether weak or strong. And the chain of this reference is **as weak as it gets** because **there is *no* chain** of narrators to this reference.

For more details on this topic, check [this](https://antishubohat.net/2016/07/28/balagh-ali/)